# Spacing between a string

Tags: java

I have a string `Week3`, 
I need to have space after `week` and number `3`,
the number after the week text may be anything,
I need Week space that number.
eg: Week 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do

```
 str=str.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=week)(?=\\d)"," ");
```

Comment: He said any number after 'Week' and it's capitalised so maybe `"(?<=Week)(?=\\d+)"` would be better.

Comment: @bmorris591 nice point..edited the regex with `ignorecase` option

Comment: The `(?i)` needs to be before the expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Week3";
    String result = "";
    for(int i=0; i< str.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
            result = result + " ";
        result= result + String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your case is really this simple, there is no need to get fancy. Just do:

```
String newString = "Week " + oldString.substring(4);
```